# Active Admin Customization in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using active admin gem. In one table i want admins page to have some extra fields apart from the default functionalities.
Is it possible to have a default active admin page + a provision to render some html.

I want something like this in picture[image]

The extra feature that i was talking was about push notification and message and that text area part

Comment: Do you mean the dashboard?

Comment: @mkis hi i have updated the question..with an image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a page with your own content, you could register a page: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html

But if you want to customise the default html strucure of the index page, you have to re-open the ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages module and override the build_page_content method. You can do this inside your app, for example create a new file in app/lib folder and override the method.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb#L62

or if you want to customise the index table:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb

Not a nice solution, but it's work. :/

Comment: can u look at the update i made in the question. I have included a pic too.. the way i want that active admin to be

Comment: Thing is i dont want to customize all the admin pages.. It should be as such for all models except for one where i have to include just a text box with a button

Comment: In this case it's enough to create your own index page: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/docs/3-index-pages. You can see exampalse in that folder. And dont forget to require your new index_page file in the top of your AA register file: require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../views/admin/your_own_index/page_file'

Comment: could you provide me with another example..or a small tutorial. Im just a beginner in this. thats why

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems index doesn't support custom rendering:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/813#issuecomment-3059957

However, you might have luck using `panel`, except in my experience that renders above the table ActiveAdmin generates.